# Exception in thread "main" after updating cucumber version

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

i have updated my cucumber version after that it is giving following exception:

```
     WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use 
   io.cucumber.core.api.cli.Main
   Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to 
  instantiate public 
 cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader,io.cucum 
  ber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry)
```

My runner Class:

```
  package hgtest.runner;


import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@CucumberOptions(plugin = "json:target/cucumber-report.json",
        features="classpath:features",
        glue="hgtest.stepdefinitions"
)
public abstract class CustomCucumberAbstractTestng extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    public CustomCucumberAbstractTestng() {
    }

    @Test(
            groups = {"cucumber"},
            description = "Runs Cucumber Feature",
            dataProvider = "features"
    )
    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }


}
```

Pom.xml is following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have updated the cucumber version from info.cuke to io.cucumber. After that it is saying Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException. There is no io.cucumber.core.api.cli.Main. I am using intellij Idea

Comment: The correct class to use is `io.cucumber.core.api.Main`, the error message was wrong (fixed in 4.5.3 https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#453-2019-07-07)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to force IntelliJ-cucumber plugin template to use the suggested io.cucumber.core.api.cli.Main, and it works.

[image: config]

Answer (score 3):

As stated by @mpkorstanje:

The correct class to use is io.cucumber.core.api.Main

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I put the dependencies below in pom.xml and implements the En interface in the class of steps the problem was solved.

```
<!-- cucumber -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the official SmartBear forum, the creator and lead developer of Cucumber Open says:

"You can safely ignore this warning. All it means is that cucumber-eclipse has not yet been updated to use Cucumber's new package structure. We have an open issue about this. If you feel strongly about it you can help us by submitting a pull request to cucumber-eclipse."

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Cucumber-Open/deprecated-Main-class-error-while-using-Cucumber-6-1-1/td-p/203642