# Cucumber "You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

Hi can any one please help me with the below error in eclipse selenium automation.

cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
Mar 24, 2020 8:03:47 AM io.cucumber.core.cli.Main run

when i run the feature file im getting this error. tries almost everything whatever i know but still facing the issue, used the latest dependencies as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177823/exception-in-thread-main-after-updating-cucumber-version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception in thread "main" after updating cucumber version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177823/exception-in-thread-main-after-updating-cucumber-version)