# Getting this error message while running cucumber feature file

Tags: maven, cucumber

```
Mar 15, 2022 9:21:30 PM cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.261s


?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
? Share your Cucumber Report with your team at https://reports.cucumber.io          ?
? Activate publishing with one of the following:                                    ?
?                                                                                   ?
? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
? Environment variable:                            CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED=true    ?
? JUnit:                                           @CucumberOptions(publish = true) ?
?                                                                                   ?
? More information at https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/environment-variables/      ?
?                                                                                   ?
? Disable this message with one of the following:                                   ?
?                                                                                   ?
? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?
? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?


?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

I also tried to

[image]

and with `"cucumber.publish.quiet=true"`

Relevant POM dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>22.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What are the versions of the plugins you are using? Can you update your post with the TEXT (no pictures) of the relevant dependencies in your POM and also your Test Runner code?

Comment: <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>22.0.0</version>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception in thread "main" after updating cucumber version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177823/exception-in-thread-main-after-updating-cucumber-version)

Comment: how are you running the feature file? (sidenote: I don;t think you need to specify the gherkin dependency; it should be a transitive dep of cucumber itself)